# Multiple rows marked after every 10 rows instead of one in Recyclerview Viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am struggling to make sure that one item with its background is colored whenever I make an update to one of its attribute through API. What's remarkable is that after every 10 rows, the next one get its colored.

On RecyclerViewAdapter, I get all items according to the API in correct order but the problem is at the if statements: instead of objects where isfound or searching equals 1, it's multiple objects who also receives the background color. How can I fix it? Here is the necessary code:

**RecyclerviewAdapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Item item=this.items.get(position);

    viewHolder.titleList.setText(item.getTitle());
    viewHolder.descriptionList.setText(item.getDescription());
    viewHolder.dateList.setText(item.getDate());

    if (item.isFound()==1){
        viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#60ad5e"));
    }

    if (item.isSearching()==1){
        viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9d3f"));
    }

    viewHolder.layoutList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Item item=items.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, item);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The recyclerview is inside the linearlayout in XML but its scrollable. Everything else works inside this code, clicking a certain item in list shos me more details of that item, etc. But its only the problem of multiple background coloring instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably combine the `if` statements and add an `else` block. The views in a `RecyclerView` are re-used as you scroll, hence the name, so you need to reset them back to default when your flag(s) are not set.

```
if (item.isFound()==1){
    viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#60ad5e"));
} else if (item.isSearching()==1){
    viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9d3f"));
} else {
    // reset the color back to default
}
```

Comment: The background setting for issearching does work but for isFound doesn't. Looks like somehow the code executes the else block automatically after the first if-statement with isFound

Comment: By the way, the code I gave you is wrong, the titlelist undert he first if should be replaced by layoutlist

Comment: this is what im using right now, the first if doesn't work

if (item.isFound()==1){
            viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#60ad5e"));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        if (item.isSearching()==1){
            viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9d3f"));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.layoutList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

Comment: It works now, thank you! Looks like I had to add else if instead for the second color